# go build not looking in $GOPATH

Tags: go, import, build, gopath

I have set $GOPATH, and importing some part of my source code which is present in $GOPATH/src.

Package I need to import is written by me and stored in GOPATH/src
I have named it as otelkafkago and it's path is GOPATH/src/otelkafkago

I have one more code base elsewhere on my HardDisk and when I try to compile that, it gives me

```
main.go:51:2: package otelkafkago is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/otelkafkago)
```

I have imported it as

```
import(
    "otelkafkago"
)
```

Following is my screen capture during build,

```
kshitijpatil@PNQ-KPATIL checkoutservice % echo $GOPATH
/Users/kshitijpatil/go/
kshitijpatil@PNQ-KPATIL checkoutservice % go build
main.go:51:2: package otelkafkago is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/otelkafkago)
kshitijpatil@PNQ-KPATIL checkoutservice % env GOPATH=/Users/kshitijpatil/go go build
main.go:51:2: package otelkafkago is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/otelkafkago)
kshitijpatil@PNQ-KPATIL checkoutservice %
```

Comment: GOPATH builds are deprecated use Go modules.

Comment: I have made my dependency as a go mod already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since Go 1.16](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#modules), the module-aware mode is enabled by default, regardless of whether a `go.mod` file is present in the current working directory or a parent directory.

> More precisely, the `GO111MODULE` environment variable now defaults to `on`. To switch to the previous behavior, set `GO111MODULE` to `auto`.

In your case, it would be easier to [migrate to go modules](https://blog.golang.org/migrating-to-go-modules), even though setting `GO111MODULE` to `auto` might help.

As commented, the first line of your `go.mod` should be:

```
module myProject
```

Your other "otelkafkago" project, it should have its own `go.mod` with `module otelkafkago` as first line, and be built first.

Comment: Getting following output :

used
GO111MODULE=auto go build 


`main.go:48:2: package otelkafkago is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/otelkafkago)`

Comment: @KshitijPatil I thought so: be to do a `go mod init myProject`, and `go build` will work.

Comment: @KshitijPatil But if you already have a go.mod, try `go mod tidy` + `go mod verify`

Comment: Can you share first line of your .mod file